# Is it possible to sync the extents of two open mxds?

Tags: arcmap, cartography

I've never seen it, and it's not vital, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to sync the extents of two open mxds?  I'm pulling an old ims service into one mxd, and have another mxd open that i will use as the basis of an ArcServer service.  I'me trying to match up the layers and symbology, and it would be cool if I could change the extent in one mxd and have it sync with the other.  Is it possible?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't claim any fame.

[Sync data frame](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14238)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way which is to use Production Mapping Views. This will then store a data frame in a geodatabase and if you point to that view in each ArcMap Session. The downside is the purchase price, but it is available. There are other applications which do achieve this like Soccet for ArcGIS which allows the 3D Soccet window to control the data frame from the Rat.

Have Fun,
CDB

Comment: telvent miner and miner arcfm has this also. document/views stored in the db

Comment: yeah I had issues when installing as seems to have a conflict with Production Mapping :)